# move the search content to different directory

Tags: shell-script, files, grep, move

I am on Oracle Solaris.

I am using:

```
grep "searchstring" filename.*
```

above command returns my search result.

Now I want to move the all the files in above search result (all the files not the search result) into a specific directory `../mydir/`.

How can I accomplish this in one command (search and move both should be done in one line command).

Answer (score 3):

From `ksh`, `bash` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`, assuming file names don't contain newline characters, you can use the split+glob operator on the output of `grep -l` (`-l` to **l**ist the files that match).

That operator is invoked by leaving the *command substitution* (`` `...` `` or `$(...)`) unquoted. Here, we tune it with the `$IFS` special variable to say which character we want to split on (here the newline character) and by disabling the `glob` part with `set -f`:

```
IFS='
'
set -f
mv $(set +f; grep -l searchstring filename*) ../mydir/
```

(we restore globbing *inside* of the command substitution (which runs in a subshell) for the expansion of `filename*`).

You can simplify it to:

```
mv $(grep -l searchstring filename*) ../mydir/
```

If you know the file names don't contain space, tab, newline, `*`, `?` or `[` characters. Above the splitting is done on newline, space and tab characters (which is the default value of `$IFS`) and globbing is performed on each word resulting of that splitting (but that's not an issue if none of the filenames contain wildcard characters).

If you can't guarantee the filenames won't contain newline characters, you could use a loop instead:

```
for f in filename*; do
  grep -q searchstring "$f" && mv "$f" ../mydir/
done
```

Comment: Hi Stephane, Can you please explain the command ? what each line does so I can understand better ? Thank you for speedy response. Do I have to type IFS=' then ' then set -f or just onetime deal ?

Comment: when i execute the one liner command i am getting error       mv: Insufficient arguments (1)
Usage: mv [-f] [-i] f1 f2
       mv [-f] [-i] f1 ... fn d1
       mv [-f] [-i] d1 d2

Comment: Also want to make sure that the search string is searching inside the files and not the filenames ?

Comment: @user73352, it looks like `grep` returns nothing. What does `set +f; grep -l searchstring filename*` return?

Comment: It returns the bunch of results with bunch of filenames

Comment: @user73352, for the one-liner command, make sure you restore globbing with `set +f` if you have issued a `set -f` earlier, or `filename*` won't be expanded otherwise.

Comment: Hi Stephane, sorry for bothering you, i am trying the following but still getting the insufficient argument error. test@test:/Path:> set +f;
test@test:/Path:> mv $(grep -l searchstring vishal_test_20140618.*) ../mydir/

mv: Insufficient arguments (1)
Usage: mv [-f] [-i] f1 f2
       mv [-f] [-i] f1 ... fn d1
       mv [-f] [-i] d1 d2